# Fluid Sim Liquid Domain is bigger then the area I dedicated to it

Tags: fluid-simulation

I´m currently doing a little fluid sim and the area of my domain is bigger then the object itself. Anyone know how to fix it? [image]

Comment: Please provide the .blend file. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/  or just paste a google drive link if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like it defaults to the bounding box of the object in world space

Answer (score 0):

A fluid domain will always enlarge around the mesh to be a world-space referenced bounding box (@Gorgious commented), so what you could do to avoid extra voxels is:

1. Rotate the fluid sim with the domain in the same orientation as the world.
2. Run and bake the fluid sim to mesh.
3. Re-rotate the sim back into the desired position.